# Adding a user to an ubuntu linux group within a shell script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, script, docker, bash-scripting

I'm writing a bash script to set up a docker application along with configuration etc.  It's intended to run in a fresh Ubuntu install and be fully automated - just hit return and wait (albeit entering a sudo password along the way).  The idea is that an ordinary user runs the script and by the end of it, they have docker installed along with the application running.  The issue I have is that part of this includes adding the user to the 'docker' group and then running further commands in the script that require the user's inclusion in the group.  Now, the command:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
```

works lovely to add them BUT the user needs to logout/login again to activate membership but I want to immediately make use of their membership in the same script to, for example:

```
docker exec blah blah
```

I've explored newgrp, but that's going to start a sub shell and won't be helpful in a fully automated script.

(Don't tell anyone, but I don't mind if the answer is a little 'hacky' in this instance.)

Answer (score 0):

I may have an answer in the 'sg' command, which I can then use during the rest of the script to execute docker commands.  E.g.

```
sg docker -c "docker run blah blah"
```

The user will still be 'undockered' at the end of the script until they log out/in but I can live with that.